# Snowflake - Check if 1st 3 Characters of string are letters

Tags: sql, sql-like, contains, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, letter

Am trying to determine how one attempts to identify, in Snowflake SQL, if a product code begins with three letters.

Suggestions?

I did just try: LEFT(P0.PRODUCTCODE,3) NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' but it didn't work.

Thanks folks

Comment: I used "not like" because I need to omit those records.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_like.html) to return a boolean value indicating whether or not your string matched the pattern you're interested in.

In your case, something like `REGEXP_LIKE(string_field_here, '[a-zA-Z]{3}.*')`

Breaking down the regular expression pattern:

- `[a-zA-Z]`: Only match letter characters, both upper and lowercase
- `{3}`: Require three of those letters
- `.*`: Allow any number of any characters after those three letters

Note: in many cases, you would need to specifically indicate the beginning/ending of the string in the pattern, but Snowflake's implementation handles that for you. From [the docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_like.html):

> The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. ''
>   automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$').
>   To match any string starting with ABC, the pattern would be 'ABC.*'.

---

You can try running these examples:

```
SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('abc', '[a-zA-Z]{3}.*') AS _abc,
       REGEXP_LIKE('123', '[a-zA-Z]{3}.*') AS _123,
       REGEXP_LIKE('abc123', '[a-zA-Z]{3}.*') AS _abc123,
       REGEXP_LIKE('123abc', '[a-zA-Z]{3}.*') AS _123abc
```

Comment: Do not forget about the parameters: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp#specifying-the-parameters-for-the-regular-expression